# Why won't my ObservableCollection<MenuItem> update on RaisePropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my WPF app, I have an `ObservableCollection<MenuItem>` which is dynamically updated to contain various category items. When the screen loads, everything is fine but changing the collection while the screen is up, and calling `RaisePropertyChanged` for the collection doesn't update the context menu.

It appears that possibly, context menu's are only loaded on control loading and can't be changed dynamically?

UPDATE: This code is dynamically creating a sub context menu based on items the user is adding or removing. My question here is why isn't the DocumentExplorerMenuOptions getter being called when RaisePropertyChanged is being called? I see RaisePropertyChanged being called but the getter never gets asked for anything.

```
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> DocumentExplorerMenuOptions {
        get {
            return new ObservableCollection<MenuItem> {                     
                new MenuItem(localizationProvider.Takeoff) {
                    Command = new DelegatingCommand(x => windowManager.ShowTakeoffWithGrid(context, selectedDocument, documentBagTasks))
                 },
                new MenuItem(localizationProvider.TakeoffImage) {
                    Command = new DelegatingCommand(x => windowManager.ShowTakeoff(context, selectedDocument, documentBagTasks))
                 },
                 ClassificationMenuItem
            };
        }
    }

    MenuItem classificationMenuItem;
    public MenuItem ClassificationMenuItem {
        get { return classificationMenuItem; }
        set { classificationMenuItem = value; }
    }

    void BuildClassificationsContextMenuItem(ICategoryBag categoryBag) {
        ClassificationMenuItem = new MenuItem(localizationProvider.ClassifyAs); 

        if (categoryBag == null) return;
        foreach (var category in (from category in categoryBag.Categories select category).OrderBy(x => x.Name)) {
            AddCategoryMenuItem(category);
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(DocumentExplorerMenuOptionsPropertyName);
    }

    void RemoveCategoryMenuItem(Category category) {
        ClassificationMenuItem.Children.RemoveAll(x => x.Text == category.Name);
        RaisePropertyChanged(DocumentExplorerMenuOptionsPropertyName);
    }

    void AddCategoryMenuItem(Category category) {
        var categoryMenuItem = new MenuItem(category.Name);
        ClassificationMenuItem.Children.Add(categoryMenuItem);
        foreach(var value in category.Values) {
            categoryMenuItem.Children.Add(new MenuItem(value.Name) { Command = new DelegatingCommand(x => classifier.Classify(new ClassificationArguments(category, value, new List<Document>(documentExplorer.SelectedDocuments).ToArray()))) });
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(DocumentExplorerMenuOptionsPropertyName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved on a similar query by me. Hope this resolves your issue.

[ContextMenu bound to ObservableCollection<MenuItem> does not refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876870/contextmenu-bound-to-observablecollectionmenuitem-does-not-refresh-data)

Answer (score 2):

The ObservableCollection property is not setup correctly. You have added everything in to the getter of that property, that doesn't really work. Try creating a private member and instantiate that on the constructor itself and add those entries there. In this case you are kind of re-instantiating the ObservableCollection for each of your View loading, because getter can get called many times.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly what you are describing. The list of categories can change constantly and I want the context sub-menu of available categories to update constantly as items are added and removed in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, if I'm reading your code correctly.  Is there a reason that you can't maintain the collection and modify it (as opposed to re-creating it) so that you don't need to `RaisePropertyChanged` at all?  That's what `ObservableCollection(of T)` does, after all.

As I'm reading it, it might as well be an `IEnumerable(of T)`.

(Creating a new `ObservableCollection(of T)` in a property getter is almost always a mistake.  A `ReadOnlyObservableCollection(of T)` makes a lot more sense in that context.)