# ContextMenu bound to ObservableCollection<MenuItem> does not refresh data

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Given the following XAML snippet:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="ContextMenuItemStyle">
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        </Style>
       <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuOptions}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContextMenuItemStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <TextBox Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ContextMenu="{StaticResource contextMenu}" />
    <Button Content="Add Menu Item" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Command="{Binding AddMenuItem}" />
 </DockPanel>
```

And View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel {

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> DocumentExplorerMenuOptions { get; set; }
    MenuItem firstMenuItem;
    MenuItem secondMenuItem;

    public MyViewModel() {
      firstMenuItem = new MenuItem("First") { Command = new DelegatingCommand(x => MessageBox.Show("First Selected") };
      secondMenuItem = new MenuItem("Second") { Command = new DelegatingCommand(x => MessageBox.Show("Second Selected") };

      MenuOptions = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem> { firstMenuItem, secondMenuItem };
      AddMenuItem = new DelegateCommand<object>(x => firstMenuItem.Children.Add(
            new MenuItem("Child of First")));

    }
    public DelegateCommand<object> AddMenuItem { get; set; }
}
```

And class:

```
public class MenuItem {
        public MenuItem(string text) {
            Text = text;
            Children = new List<MenuItem>();
        }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public List<MenuItem> Children { get; private set; }
        public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    }
```

Clicking the button *does* add the child to firstMenuItem but it does *not* appear in the context menu of the TextBox.

I can't figure out how to make the context menu show the dynamic content of the context menu. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not bind to a collection of MenuItems but rather to a more data-driven collection which may contain the MenuItem header, a command which is executed upon click and another collection of such items for the sub-items. Then you could use a (Hierarchical)DataTemplate to generate the menu on the fly. Doing so would probably take care of update issues if your datatype implements the necessary interfaces.

**Edit:** You seem to have such a datatype already, could you post its code?

**Edit2:** I think the problem is that you use a style that explicitly needs to be applied (it is probably only being applied to the main context menu, not the sub-items), as noted before i'd suggest a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

**Edit3:** lol...

```
public List<MenuItem> Children { get; private set; }
```

Of course it's not going to update if it's a `List` and not an `ObservableCollection`.

(The class is quite badly designed overall by the way, Lists should normally not even have a private setter, they should be properties with just a getter to a `readonly` field)

Comment: @ H.B. Added the class to the snippets.

Comment: @ H.B. The original sample is taken from http://www.julmar.com/blog/mark/2009/04/21/UsingMVVMWithMenusInWPF.aspx .

Comment: @H.B. Thank you.. I will now go hang my head in shame! This has been plaguing me for 2 days now.

Comment: Oh my, maybe should have asked earlier :) , glad i could help!

Comment: This has a problem. If you make the Template contain a MenuItem, it renders a MenuItem in a MenuItem. Because every element in the Context menu is a MenuItem. So..... Binding to an Observable collection of MenuItems would work fine. My alternative to this that I can think of, is to make the DataTemplate a button with the command styled to be a textblock, but then if you click on the menuitem but outside of the textblock, it doesn't perform the command. I'm stuck on this on.

Comment: @LeeLouviere: I do not know what you are talking about, i'd never suggest putting a `MenuItem` in a Template. If you want to have commands use the `ItemContainerStyle` and bind `Command`. Tne `DataTemplate` is usually not needed, for the text you can also use the `ItemContainerStyle` to set the `DisplayMemberPath`.

Comment: @H.B. Sorry, misunderstood this "Then you could use a (Hierarchical)DataTemplate to generate the menu on the fly".

Comment: @LeeLouviere: Well, to clarify, if it is hierarchical you do need `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, but you should not need to set its template as the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` also has an `ItemContainerStyle` to bind `Command` and `DisplayMemberPath`.

Comment: @H.B. So, <HDT><ICS><Style><Setter Property="Command" Value="{Bind}> ... Thanks, I didn't think of that at all.